# how to put numpy arrays having list component in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three numpy arrays. One is a purely numpy array but others are a numpy arrays composed of lists with different lengths. I want to do a calculation in a for loop but do not know how I can do it. At the moment I can do it only for three pure numpy arrays without any for loop.
my input data are:

```
aa= array([array([[1.37100000e+03, 4.00000000e+00, ...,  2.00000000e+00]]),
            array([[6.25439286e+01, 2.68664193e+01, ..., 5.86345693e+01]]), 
            array([[5.25980126e+01, 1.99945789e+01, ..., 9.25987458e+01]])], dtype=object)
```

`aa` has three arrays (but in reality it has much more arrays) which each array is composed of a big list with thousands of rows and 20 columns. Numbers rows in each array changes but number of columns in all of them is 20. I made it because I have jagged lists and can not make a numpy array by them. Structure of my second data set is also exactly the same as first one (three arrays composed of lists), but it has its own values:

```
bb= array([array([[2000, 15478, ...,  956410]]),
          array([[61478, 98572, ..., 7801561]]), 
          array([[98601, 20198, ..., 6021981]])], dtype=object)
```

the third data set:

```
cc= array([[3., 1.66666667, 1.5, ..., 1.66666667],
                               .....
           [2., 98.33333333, 28.5, ..., 98.33333333]])
```

`cc` is a pure 2d numpy array. It has thousands of rows and 12 columns. It is merged by three arrays which has four columns. I can say it has three parts based on its columns (I mean `cc[:,0:4]`, `cc[:,4:8]` and `cc[:,8:12]`).
In my first iteration, I want to compare the data of first array of `aa` and also the first split of `cc`. I want to do some calculation on all rows of some columns of `aa`'s first array (`aa[:,17:20]`) and `cc[:,1:4]`. The next one should be again the all the rows and the same columns (17:20) from the second array of `aa` and `cc[:,5:8]`. The next one also again columns 17:20 from the third array of `aa` and `cc[:,9:12]`. For this step of my code, I do not need first column of each split of `cc` (columns 0, 4 and 8). In the next step, I use `cc[:,0]` in my first iteration to calculate something (`u`). `cc[:,4]` is for the next iterationa and `cc[:,8]` for the last one. Then, all data stored as first array of `bb` should be called. My code at the moment is working for pure numpy `aa`, `bb` and `cc`. Finally my loop should calculate three `new_elements` rather than one. So, first iteration of should use all rows of some columns of `aa`'s first array (`aa[:,17:20]`), `cc[:,1:4]`, `cc[:,0]` and all the data of first array of `bb`. This is my code used for one single iteration for three pure numpy arrays (without list component):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
distances=distance.cdist(aa[:,17:20],cc[:,1:4]) # THIS LINE NEEDS ITERATION
min_d=np.argmin(distances, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
z=np.array([])
for i in min_d:
        u=cc[i,0] # THIS LINE NEEDS ITERATION
        z=np.array([np.append(z,u)]).reshape(-1,1)
final=np.concatenate((aa,z), axis =1) # THIS LINE NEEDS ITERATION
new_vol=final[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)
new_elements=np.concatenate((bb,new_vol), axis =1) # THIS LINE NEEDS ITERATION
new_elements=np.delete(new_elements,[-1],1).astype(int)
```

Here, I add a simple data set which mimics my code. But the reality is what I explained about my data.

```
aa= array([[72.70518085,  3.65801928, 51.02667157],
          [60.20252523,  3.79943938, 40.83221737]])
bb= array([[2571,    4,    2],
          [2572,    4,    2]])
cc= array([[ 3. , 25. ,  7.5, 25. ],
          [ 2. , 25. ,  7.5, 75. ]])
```

The result will also be:

```
new_elements= array([[2571,    4,    2],
                     [2572,    4,    2]])
```

Please note that for this simplified data set, `aa[:,17:20]` in my code should be replaced with `aa`. To address it again, In my real data `aa` and `bb` have another structure but `aa` is the same what I addressed in my simplified case study.
In advance, thanks for devoting time.

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that can be run?  Like, the code to construct the structure of each array (doesn't need thousands of elements just to test), since that's not very clear, and possibly an expected result based on your current code?  Also please make sure your current code is giving the answers you expect, so our answers will be helpful.

Comment: Dear @DanielF, Thanks for your feedback. Problem is that a python package is giving me big data sets. For example `aa` in the simplest case is composed of three lists and each list has has 20 columns. That's why I can't write real data here. I want to put my code in a for loop. At the moment it is only doing the calculation one time but I want to iterate over my input data (`aa`, `bb` and `cc`). My code is giving answer to three pure numpy arrays. But, I want to make a for loop and two of my inputs are also changing to numpy arrays made by list (I told it because it affects the indexing).

Comment: It's not easy, I know, but part of asking a good question is writing good, minimal test code.  Right now I can't follow what you have as input and output from the code you have, so I can't really help.  You don't need to give the full ML output, just some code that makes similar, smaller-scale data (using `np.random` and your shapes work, but make sure to include your random seed so we can replicate).  This is good practice anyway, since as you're finding debugging code by running big datasets through it can take a long time.

Comment: Dear @DanielF, Yes, you are absolutely right. I am updating my question with a sample data set.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you work with lists, instead of converting everything to a "real" numpy array with a numeric dtype? As I understand your data is 2D NxM, so that should be feasible.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, The reason is that I am making them through a for loop. In each lop I have numpy arrays with different lengths. Then, the only way that I know to keep all of results of iterations is to store each result as a list and finally make numpy array with these list. In fact, they are jagged lists. Is there a way to convert them to a pure numpy array? I read this solution and decided to keep them as pure numpy arrays? If yes, please let me know. I appreciate it.

Comment: I understand that you have multiple arrays with different number of rows each, but same number of columns. It is probably easier and much more performant that instead of storing an array of lists to use a list of arrays. Each element in the list will be a NxM array, where N can change. You just iterate over the outer list then, and the internal arrays can be processed at numpy speed.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa- Aha, Thanks for your hint. You mean for example I can say `aa` is `[[[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]], [[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]`. Did I get it right? Then, the for loop will be run easier and faster? How about indexing. Have you any idea how I can run my for loop regarding that all my input are lists rather than numpy arrys?

Comment: You just loop over the list, and you can use fancy-indexing for the "inner" numpy arrays.

Comment: Aha, Thanks for your hints. I try to maybe solve it.